# Ajax Error when Developer Toolbar is open in Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am facing an issue when click on any button in a web page after opening developer tool bar, getting sometimes ajax error 737 and some cases 500 internal server error. After that I need to logout from web application and login again back in order to work all the buttons properly. Again if I open developer tool 
bar I will get the same error. In Firefox it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling developer tool bar in chorme

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm

Comment: I tried uninstalling chrome and installed again. But not working. Developer toolbar reinstalled still not working. Developer Tools taken from More tools --> Developer Tools ( Ex: Console, Scripts, Network, Resource tabs are there in Developer tool )

Comment: Can't answer without more error detail.
Try using fiddler and check the request/response detail when you open developer tool
http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. There was a underscore-min.js in the master page which was causing the issue. After commenting out the file it got passed.